# form data not uploading file to mysql database

Tags: mysql, reactjs, axios

I am trying to upload information from react frontend using formData and I checked the backend using postman everything is working fine but formData is not passing the file to the backend. this is my code

react frontend component

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { use state } from 'react'

function NotificationSecond() {
    let server ="http://localhost:3456";
    let address = `${server}/user/notification`

  const [Data, setData] = useState({
    assigned_to:"",
    message:""
  })
  const [response, setresponce] = useState();
  
    let submitter = (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        let forForm = new FormData();
        forForm.append('assigned_to',Data.assigned_to)
        forForm.append('message',Data.message)


        axios({
            method:"post",
            url:address,
            data:forForm,
            headers: {"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
        }).then((data)=>{
            setresponce(data.data)
        }).catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err)
        })
    }

    let inputHandler = (e)=>{
        switch (e.target.value) {
            case "assigned_to":setData((pre)=>{return {...pre,assigned_to:e.target.value}})
                
                break;
            case "message":setData((pre)=>{return {...pre,message:e.target.value}})
                
                break;
        
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    if(response){
        return <div>
            <h1>this is response</h1>
        </div>
    }else{
     return (
     <div>
        <form action="" onSubmit={submitter} >

        <select name="assigned_to" id="" onChange={inputHandler}>
            <option value="one">one</option>
            <option value="two">two</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name='message' onChange={inputHandler} />
        <button>submit</button>
        </form>
     </div>
  )
}
}
export default NotificationSecond
```

---

backend controler

```
import Econnection  from "../server.js";
let notification =(req,res)=>{
    const {assigned_to,message}=req.body
    let value = [assigned_to,message];
    let notificationAdder = `INSERT INTO notification(assigned_to,message) VALUES (?)`;

    Econnection.query(notificationAdder,[value],(err)=>{
         if(err){
            console.log(err)
            res.send('uploading notifications was not successful')
         }else{
            res.send({
                forThanking : `Uploaded successfully,Thank you!`,
                forHomePageReturn: `Click Here To Go Back To Home Page`
            })
         }
    })
}

export default notification;
```

---

```
backend routing 
import express from 'express';


import notification from '../Controaller/noticationControler.js';

let notificationRoute = express.Router();

notificationRoute.post('/notification',notification)
```

### `enter code here`export default notificationRoute

i uploaded the backend just in case but all things work fine in backend according to my test and all the swithc and state is also working but i dont think axiios is posting the data to mysql through the created route , the database for this only contain two colums which says "assigned_to" ,"message.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the form data method was not being appended to the input values; I created an object with a different name and pass the object name to the axios method, and it worked fine. Also removed the header part from axios.

```js
let file = {
  assigned_to: Data.assigned_to,
  message : Data.message
}

axios({
  method:"post",
  url:address,
  data:file,
})
  .then((data) => {
    setresponce(data.data)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  })
}
```